# referencing individual dicts in the one line tree

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree, key

I'm using this [gist's](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250/) one-line tree to grab info from excel easily.  Here's an example of the tree from the site:

```
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
taxonomy = tree()
taxonomy['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia']['Carnivora']['Felidae']['Felis']['cat']
taxonomy['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia']['Carnivora']['Felidae']['Panthera']['lion']
taxonomy['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia']['Carnivora']['Canidae']['Canis']['dog']
```

and then this to convert it into dicts for pretty printing:

```
def dicts(t):
    try:
        return dict((k, dicts(t[k])) for k in t)
    except TypeError:
        return t
```

**CLARIFICATION**

How do you return keys from a tree? Specifically, the first three layers of keys in the tree would be gotten and put into a list.  An example would be:

```
('Animalia', 'Chordata', 'Mammalia','Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Convolvulaceae')
```

of

```
{'Animalia': {'Chordata': {'Mammalia': {'Carnivora': {'Canidae': {'Canis': {'coyote': {},
                                                                        'dog': {}}},
                                                  'Felidae': {'Felis': {'cat': {}},
                                                              'Panthera': {'lion': {}}}},
                                    'Cetacea': {'Balaenopteridae': {'Balaenoptera': {'blue whale': {}}}}}}},
 'Plantae': {'Solanales': {'Convolvulaceae': {'Ipomoea': {'sweet potato': {}}},
                       'Solanaceae': {'Solanum': {'potato': {},
                                                  'tomato': {}}}}}}
```

Comment: The edited version of the post is still completely unclear. The original version seemed to be asking for the individual subdicts. From your comments, that wasn't what you wanted, but then your edited question explicitly says that's _exactly_ what you want. I've tried to edit my answer to handle all of the questions you seem to have asked, but until you make it clear which one you _are_ asking, nobody's likely to reopen your question.

Comment: @abarnert I've re-edited it again.  Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the new version of your question (in your comment), what you want is all of the keys of the top-level dict, and, for each one, all of the keys of the corresponding second-level dict, and again the same for the third.

In other words, you want a list of all of the paths through the tree, but truncated at the third level. So, let's just do a depth-first walk through the tree, and truncate at the third level.

First, let's write a simple depth-first path finder:

```
def paths(tree, path=()):
    for key, subtree in tree.items():
        if subtree:
            yield from paths(subtree, path + (key,))
        else:
            yield path + (key,)
```

Now, let's truncate it at depth 3:

```
def prefix_paths(prefix_length, tree, path=()):
    for key, subtree in tree.items():
        if subtree and len(path) + 1 < prefix_length:
            yield from prefix_paths(prefix_length, subtree, path + (key,))
        else:
            yield path + (key,)
```

And that's it:

```
>>> results = list(prefix_paths(3, taxonomy))
>>> print(results)
[('Animalia', 'Chordata', 'Mammalia'),
 ('Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Solanaceae'),
 ('Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Convolvulaceae')]
```

---

Actually, what you describe in the comment is that you want a single tuple of all of the keys in the top three levels. But you can easily get that from the above. Just flatten the list and eliminate duplicates:

```
>>> flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
>>> keys = flatten(prefix_paths(3, taxonomy))
>>> unique_keys = tuple(set(keys))
>>> print(unique_keys)
('Chordata', 'Convolvulaceae', 'Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Animalia', 'Mammalia', 'Solanaceae')
```

(By the way, the order is completely indeterminate, because that's how dictionaries work; the fact that I happened to get the same order as in your comment is just an accident, and you should not rely on it…)

---

Meanwhile, here's my answer to the original version of your problem (which is still what's asked in the question…).

It's just this:

```
taxonomy['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia']
```

Or, if you want the "clean" version:

```
dicts(taxonomy)['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia']
```

Or, alternatively:

```
dicts(taxonomy['Animalia']['Chordata']['Mammalia'])
```

---

If you prefer, you can write a wrapper function.

If you know it's always going to be three keys:

```
def subtree(tree, three_keys):
    return tree[three_keys[0]][three_keys[1]][three_keys[2]]
```

If you want it to work with an arbitrary number of keys:

```
def subtree(tree, keys):
    while keys:
        tree, keys = tree[keys[0]], keys[1:]
    return tree
```

Then:

```
subtree(taxonomy, ('Animalia', 'Chordata', 'Mammalia'))
```

Again, you can pass either `taxonomy` or the overall result to `dicts` to get the "clean" version.

All of the above give you:

```
{'Carnivora': {'Canidae': {'Canis': {'dog': {}}},
```

'Felidae': {'Felis': {'cat': {}}, 'Panthera': {'lion': {}}}}}

(or its messy `defaultdict` equivalent).

If you want to make it even nicer:

```
pprint.pprint(subtree(dicts(taxonomy), ('Animalia', 'Chordata', 'Mammalia')))
```

… which gives you:

```
{'Carnivora': {'Canidae': {'Canis': {'dog': {}}},
               'Felidae': {'Felis': {'cat': {}},
                           'Panthera': {'lion': {}}}}}}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant that I wanted all possible keys in a list format.  So the final list would be: ('Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Convolvulaceae','Animalia', 'Chordata', 'Mammalia')

Comment: Actually, I think I could probably could convert the tree I have to a subtree and use something similar in structure to:

    def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}

except with a def that returns the first three layers of keys into a list....I'm just spitballing.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was asking for your second answer!  Worked awesome.

Comment: To clarify, by "second answer" you mean the flattened list of unique keys in the top 3 levels: `('Chordata', 'Convolvulaceae', 'Plantae', 'Solanales', 'Animalia', 'Mammalia', 'Solanaceae')`, right?

Comment: Anyway, for future reference, whenever your question is "For a list or dict, I'd iterate over the items and ___, but what do I do for a tree?", the answer is usually something closely related to "Depth-first walk the nodes and ___". So, you might want to play with a few different ways of writing a depth-first walk (iterative vs. recursive, generator vs. list-returning function, etc.) to solidify the idea in your head.